# g++ can't locate the installed i386 packages on x64 debian

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-platform

Compiling multi-arch on Debian (and presumably other Linux versions too, according to the amount of frustrating forum posts found by Google so far), really sucks. Yet I've managed to unravel some steps that should one day lead to desired binary. First thing to do is to allow multi-arch package management and select desired architecture:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

After this you can add `:i386` after any library name during `apt-get`, provided that library supports it. So I did this for all libraries I need. Check this neat command to list all i386 libraries on the system:

```
XXXXX@ebianvirtualbox:~/$ dpkg -l|grep :i386
ii  gcc-4.8-base:i386                      4.8.4-1                              i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.9-base:i386                      4.9.2-10                             i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libasan0:i386                          4.8.4-1                              i386         AddressSanitizer -- a fast memory error detector
ii  libatomic1:i386                        4.9.2-10                             i386         support library providing __atomic built-in functions
ii  libboost-dev:i386                      1.55.0.2                             i386         Boost C++ Libraries development files (default version)
ii  libboost1.55-dev:i386                  1.55.0+dfsg-3                        i386         Boost C++ Libraries development files
ii  libc6:i386                             2.19-18+deb8u1                       i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dev:i386                         2.19-18+deb8u1                       i386         GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
ii  libc6-i686:i386                        2.19-18+deb8u1                       i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries [i686 optimized]
ii  libgcc-4.8-dev:i386                    4.8.4-1                              i386         GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1:i386                           1:4.9.2-10                           i386         GCC support library
ii  libgomp1:i386                          4.9.2-10                             i386         GCC OpenMP (GOMP) support library
ii  libitm1:i386                           4.9.2-10                             i386         GNU Transactional Memory Library
ii  libquadmath0:i386                      4.9.2-10                             i386         GCC Quad-Precision Math Library
ii  libssl-dev:i386                        1.0.1k-3+deb8u1                      i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
ii  libssl1.0.0:i386                       1.0.1k-3+deb8u1                      i386         Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - shared libraries
ii  libstdc++-4.8-dev:i386                 4.8.4-1                              i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3 (development files)
ii  libstdc++6:i386                        4.9.2-10                             i386         GNU Standard C++ Library v3
ii  linux-libc-dev:i386                    3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4                i386         Linux support headers for userspace development
ii  zlib1g:i386                            1:1.2.8.dfsg-2+b1                    i386         compression library - runtime
ii  zlib1g-dev:i386                        1:1.2.8.dfsg-2+b1                    i386         compression library - development
```

Unfortunately installing libraries just does not solve the problem. This is the very latest output I pulled out of `ld` (gcc linker):

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_serialization
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_date_time
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_signals
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `_ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEED1Ev' changed from 194 in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../liblog4cplus.so to 67 in ./source/R220/TTServer_cpp_d.o
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `_ZNSt6vectorISsSaISsEED2Ev' changed from 194 in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../liblog4cplus.so to 67 in ./source/R220/TTServer_cpp_d.o
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `_ZNSt12_Destroy_auxILb0EE9__destroyIPSsEEvT_S3_' changed from 170 in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../liblog4cplus.so to 55 in ./source/R220/TTServer_cpp_d.o
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEESbIT_T0_T1_ERKS6_S8_' changed from 119 in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../liblog4cplus.so to 98 in ./source/loader/R220Loader_cpp_d.o
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

This is a result of following linker setup:

> `-m32 -L /lib/ -lboost_serialization -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_signals -lboost_iostreams -lboost_system -llog4cplus -lcrypto -lssl -lm -shared`

This means all libboost files were not found as well as  the standard C++ library. That's bad, I've installed them and I don't know what else should I be doing... Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried doing this in a chroot environment which is only i386? The cause of your errors and warnings you get might be related to the fact that you use a 64-bit system and in fact have the 64-bit libs as well, right? I would try chroot or change your environment especially search the paths so only i386 libraries are considered.

Comment: Well I heard of chroot, but I was hoping multiarch is already considered functional. Do you have any idea how could I restrict the paths to i386 only? Maybe how to check where every of the i386 libraries is installed?

Comment: I think you need to change the PATH variable. Take a look at it with ``echo $PATH`` try to remove the 64-bit paths and ensure the 32-bit ones are taken and do another new export. I think multiarch really works for executing the programs but for building I'm not sure to be honest. I always had issues and it was hard to get everything build with a config like this. I use chroot for 32-bit builds. It's the easiest way in my opinion. https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot.